# swiper slider not working for foreach loop data

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I am using swiper slider to show data getting on a foreach loop.but it only showing the first data of the loop,others are not showing or sliding. In inspection I am getting the data of the loop,but in view slider is not working.

blade.php code

```
<div class="swiper-container text-center">
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                            @foreach($course->course_slots as $slot)
                                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                                        <div class="card card-body">
                                            <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
                                            <p class="text-center">Meets {{ count($slot->schedules) }} more time</p>
                                                
                                          
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                        <br><br>
                    </div>
```

js part:

```
   let swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        slidesPerView: 1,
        spaceBetween: 20,
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
            clickable: true,
            dynamicBullets: true,
        },
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
        simulateTouch: false
```

Comment: edited. but same problem

Comment: Your code works fine. The problem is in "simulateTouch" parameter. If you remove it then you may scroll the slides with your mouse in the desktop mode.